# Raspberry Pi downaload of CV2 gone wrong

Tags: pi-4, linux, opencv

I have installed the CV2 library on my `raspberry pi 4`, but when I proceeded to import it I got this error:

```
ImportError: libjasper.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I proceeded to search the web (and ask chatGPT the great) and I was advised to make write some commands on the command prompt. First I updated my CMake to the latest version, but every command that followed gave a `302` error.

I have tried to use these commands to combat the situation:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get clear
```

and some others. No command helped.

I tried also to change the mirror server. I am from Israel, so I used Isreal's link. And it just makes every command after return `package could not be located`.

I have no idea how to proceed from here. Any help would be appreciated.
fyi, I am new to raspberry pi so maybe I am missing something?

Comment: you have a problem with installing a library on a Linux computer ... research at a Linux Q&A site ... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: At a guess you did not install cv2 from the standard repository.  However it is not our job to guess at what you may have done.

Comment: used pip.. `pip install opencv-python` @joan

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Are you using a virtual environment? If you are not using a virtual environment you installed the library for Python 2.x, not Python3. As Python 2.x is no longer supported you should be using Python 3 which (if not using a virtual environment) would require something like pip3 install opencv-python.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I am using python 3.7.2 or 3.7.4 can’t recall the exact one. I don’t use a venv. 
When I’ll be home I will try to install it your way. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @SteveRobillard tried it with pip3 and still the same error

Comment: this thread may help https://github.com/amymcgovern/pyparrot/issues/34

Comment: @SteveRobillard hey Steve, I tried to download atlas but any `sudo apt-get install` just gives me a 302 error

Comment: I believe I found the problem, port 80 is closed. I will check if I can install `apt-get packages after I'll open the port.

Comment: Update, my ISP wanted me to buy a subscription to a private non-changing IP Address, well, nope.